# pyPdf extracting info from IndirectObject

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am writing a script that will read the creation and modified dates of pdf files. I am using pyPdf package in Python

I have the following code

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

input1 = PdfFileReader(file('myfile','rb'))

input1.input1.getDocumentInfo()
```

this code returns

```
{'/Producer': IndirectObject(185, 0), '/CreationDate': IndirectObject(186, 0), '/ModDate': IndirectObject(186, 0)}
```

I am not sure how to extract the information from these IndirectObject, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know pyPdf that well, but [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/) has some similar functionality, and (IMHO -- I'm the author) a somewhat more simplistic interface.  pdfrw maps structures in PDF files into Python structures.  Here is an example session:

```
>>> from pdfrw import PdfReader
>>> x = PdfReader('some_random.pdf')
```

What is `x`?  It's the trailer dictionary of the PDF file, which is mapped into a (subclassed) Python dictionary:

```
>>> list(x)
['/Size', '/Info', '/Root']
```

To access items in this dictionary, you could use dictionary-style lookup, but since all the standard Adobe names start with a slash and a letter, pdfrw supports attribute lookups as well for convenience.  It's basically dictionaries and lists all the way down.  Info is just another dictionary:

```
>>> x.Info
{'/ModDate': '(D:20130802052610)',
 '/Producer': '(ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-04 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org)',
 '/Title': '(US4441207.pdf)',
 '/CreationDate': '(D:20130802052610)'}
```

So you can pull out the Producer the same way:

```
>>> x.Info.Producer
'(ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-04 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org)'
```

The Producer's value is a PDF string -- that's what the parentheses are about.  You can strip them with the `decode()` method:

```
>>> x.Info.Producer.decode()
'ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-04 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org'
```

Likewise with the CreationDate:

```
>>> x.Info.CreationDate.decode()
'D:20130802052610'
```

The pdfrw documentation isn't really great, but there are a lot of examples on github and a few here on SO.